# apache requestheader environment variable

Tags: linux, apache, http, http-headers

I want to set the value of SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN on the RequestHeader in apache, the below does not work...

```
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN

  ProxyPass        http://x.x.x.x/
  ProxyPassReverse http://x.x.x.x/
  Header add X-FILTER-Username %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}
  RequestHeader set X-FILTER-Username %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}
```

any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to solve using this

```
  Header add X-RStudio-Username "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
  RequestHeader set X-FILTER-Username "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
```